# Inventory update challenge

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve an algorithm challenge.

Here is the prompt:

> Compare and update the inventory stored in a 2D array against a second 2D array of a fresh delivery. Update the current existing inventory item quantities (in arr1). If an item cannot be found, add the new item and quantity into the inventory array. The returned inventory array should be in alphabetical order by item.

Here is my code:

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    // All inventory must be accounted for or you're fired!

  var myMap = new Map();

  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    myMap.set(arr1[i][1], arr1[i][0]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
    if (!myMap.has(arr2[1])){
      myMap.set(arr2[i][1], 0);
    }
    myMap.set(arr2[i][1], myMap.get(arr2[i][1]) + arr2[i][0]);    
  }

  var arr3 = [];

  // sorting
  myMap.forEach(function(value, key){
    var i = 0;

    while (i < arr3.length && key > arr3[i][1])
      i++;

    arr3.splice(i, 0, [value, key]);
  });

  return arr3;

}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fvgdL84/

Here is what should happen:

> updateInventory([[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]], [[2, "Hair Pin"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], [7, "Toothpaste"]])

should return

> [[88, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [3, "Hair Pin"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [5, "Microphone"], [7, "Toothpaste"]].

Edit: I think I've already got a solution. However, there seems to be a bug in the code that I can't seem to find. I need help with that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map if you want, I did something similar with simply creating an object from the 'current' array so that I could maintain the reference, which makes things a lot easier since the function apparently can't simply return a new object to replace 'current' with.

```
// Example inventory lists
var current = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];

var updated = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

function toObj(arr){
  var obj = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    obj[item[1]] = item[0];
  });
  return obj;
}

function updateInventory(current, updated){
  var inventory = toObj(current);
  updated.forEach((item) => {
    inventory[item[1]] = item[0];
  });

  current.length = 0;

  Object.keys(inventory).forEach((key) => {
    var count = inventory[key];
    current.push([count, key]);
  });
}

updateInventory(current, updated);
console.log(current);
```

That creates the correct replacement of the current inventory.

https://jsfiddle.net/t6x5eag4/

Answer (score 0):

I found what the bug was. Instead of arr[i][1], I used arr[i], which resulted in the program not being able to find a previous entry in the map to overwrite. It led to the program simply adding new keys instead of modifying the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    const store = {};

    arr1.concat(arr2).forEach(([value, key]) => {
        store[key] = (store[key] || 0) + value;
    });

    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(store).sort();
    
    return sortedKeys.map(key => [store[key], key])
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).